# Can't install auth.group fixture when testing - django 1.7

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have a django project and I am trying to write some tests for it. However, my `initial_data` fixtures cause an error when running the test.

The error that I am getting is:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Problem installing fixture 'accounts/fixtures/initial_data.json': Could not load auth.Group(pk=1): relation "auth_group" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE "auth_group" SET "name" = '...
```

If I rename my fixture to something other than `initial_data` so that it doesn't get loaded by default, it works, but I don't want to rename my fixtures, because that would mean that I can no longer run `loaddata` without arguments.

I have found [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23031), but my project does not have any initial migrations. Also, I have other fixtures which are loaded just fine.

So far, I have tried:

- flushing my development database, as well as deleting any possible migration files
- deleting and re-creating my virtual env
- changing the order of my apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`
- calling the flush command in the `.setUp()` method.

I should mention that I am using the [APITestCase](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#test-cases) from django-rest-framework.

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so finally, it seems that the problem wasn't just when I was testing. When I changed back to running my server, I noticed I was getting the same error.

Every single similar problem I found had something to do with migrations, but I didn't even had those, because running `./manage.py makemigrations` was not generating them.

So I ended up doing `./manage.py makemigrations *app_name*` for each of my apps, and everything started working again ...